# Filtering an Observable based on a past value of another

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

So I have two observables `click$` and `focus$`. I want the click to go through *only if there haven't been any focus events in the past 500ms*.

I have tried skipWhile. But I'm lost trying to figure out what to put inside it.

```
click$.skipWhile(/* No focus$ events in the past 500ms*/).subscribe()
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want by composing an observable that's based on the focus events. Like this:

```
const focusedClick$ = focus$
  // Switch to the click observable, but only after the specified
  // duration has elapsed:
  .switchMap(() => Observable.timer(500).ignoreElements().concat(click$));
```

If it's somehow possible to have a click event without a preceding focus event, you can solve that problem using the `startWith` operator:

```
const focusedClick$ = focus$
  // Map the focus event to a duration:
  .mapTo(500)
  // Start the observable chain with a duration of zero, so click
  // events don't have to be preceded by focus events:
  .startWith(0)
  // Switch to the click observable, but only after the specified
  // duration has elapsed:
  .switchMap(duration => Observable.timer(duration).ignoreElements().concat(click$));
```

Comment: But what if the focus$ observable is empty?

Comment: @cartant Thanks for your answer. But like gawick mentioned. What if there are no focus events? This would not work then.

Comment: I've added another solution that does not require a focus event to precede a click event.

Comment: Thanks I'll accept this answer . But is there a reason why we cannot do this based on the click$ observable?

Comment: I thought it was the simplest way, that's all. These solutions only subscribe to `click$` when the events are wanted. I thought that would be simpler than always observing clicks and disregarding some, but not others. I'll have a think about it later - maybe - to see if there's a `click$`-based solution worth sharing.